# In software development context, is "hanging task" or "hung task" a good term for a process that isn't making progress?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-request

At the first glance it seems to me like it is. I think I have heard it being used in this context. Google lists this as one of the meanings of the word "hang".

But then I googled "hung" and came across [this page at dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/hung) which says that it's something vulgar.

So, is it okay to use? Is there a better word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Hanging" is better than "hung" but not because of the possibly perceived vulgarity.

It's just because it's better understood, in this context, as meaning what you want it to mean.

Incidentally, I would not worry about "hung" being an improper and vulgar word to use, unless you say "well hung", which indeed generally means "possessed of an impressively-sized penis".